# Some doubts about references keyword in an association table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, rdbms

I am pretty new in Microsoft **SQL Server** and I am not into DB.

I have the following doubt: I have a table named **VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference** that is an association for the two tables: **VulnerabilityAlertDocument** and **VulnerabilityReference**.

The **VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference** contains only two fields that are:

- **VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId**
- **VulnerabilityReferenceId**

Executing this query that show me some information about my **VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference** table:

```
sp_help VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference;
```

I obtain this output:

```
VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId, VulnerabilityReferenceId
(n/a)
FOREIGN KEY FK_AlertDocument_Reference_AlertDocument    No Action   No Action   Enabled

FOREIGN KEY FK_AlertDocument_Reference_Reference    No Action   No Action   Enabled

PRIMARY KEY (clustered) PK_AlertDocument_Reference  (n/a)   (n/a)   (n/a)

Is_For_Replication

(n/a)
Is_For_Replication
VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId
REFERENCES EarlyWarningsV2.dbo.VulnerabilityAlertDocument (Id)
VulnerabilityReferenceId
REFERENCES EarlyWarningsV2.dbo.VulnerabilityReference (Id)
```

What exactly means this specific section?

```
Is_For_Replication
VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId
REFERENCES EarlyWarningsV2.dbo.VulnerabilityAlertDocument (Id)
VulnerabilityReferenceId
REFERENCES EarlyWarningsV2.dbo.VulnerabilityReference (Id)
```

It means that the **VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId** field of the association table is bind to the primary key value of the **VulnerabilityAlertDocument** table and that the **VulnerabilityReferenceId** field of the association table is bind to the **VulnerabilityReference** primary key?

So it means that if I insert a new row in my **VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference** have to exist a row VulnerabilityAlertDocument with this primary key and another row in VulnerabilityReference with this primary key?

Is my interpretation correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation is correct.

```
VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId REFERENCES EarlyWarningsV2.dbo.VulnerabilityAlertDocument (Id)
```

Indicates, the value that you are going to insert into column VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId of VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference should be already existing in column named 'Id' in table VulnerabilityAlertDocument. ( else VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId can be a NULL, if that is permitted ).

Similar is the case of the table VulnerabilityReferenceId.